# html table first column width not respecting pixel width

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with the following column sizing set. The first two are fixed, and the last one is set to occupy remaining space. However only the first `th` is *not* respecting width attribute (if set in pixels). It shows up proper width if I set in percent. Seems strange to me because I couldn't find any styles conflicting with it either. I even tried adding a column before "User" column, in which case User gets proper space as specified and the new column tries to spread.

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="100">User</th>
            <th width="150">Date</th>
            <th width="">Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

What could be the possible cause for this? Why does it work for percent and not pixels? I even tried giving table width in px instead of %.

Answer (score 1):

because in html tag width attributes use px if you want to full width table. define the width of table in css

Answer (score 0):

do you have any style in your css that defining the table tag globally?

```
<table width="100%" border="1px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="100px">User</th>
            <th width="150px">Date</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

it works fine on the https://jsfiddle.net/mqwh0cpn/